# Unable to get property 'add' of undefined or null reference while using angular-material-fileupload

Tags: angular, angular-material

//app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {ModalModule} from 'angular-custom-modal';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import { TableDemoComponent } from './table-demo/table-demo.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { FileUploadModalComponent } from './table-demo/file-upload-modal/file-upload-modal.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { TestModalComponent } from './test-modal/test-modal.component';
import {MatDialogModule} from'@angular/material';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatFileUploadModule } from 'angular-material-fileupload';
import { MyDialogComponent } from './my-dialog/my-dialog.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TableDemoComponent,
    FileUploadModalComponent,
    TestModalComponent,
    MyDialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatTableModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ModalModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFileUploadModule
  ],
  entryComponents:[
    MyDialogComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

//app.component.html

```
<div [fileUploadInputFor]="fileUploadQueue" class="upload-drop-zone"></div>
```

//app.component.ts

```
   import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-demo',
  templateUrl: './table-demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-demo.component.scss']
})
export class TableDemoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }


  @HostListener('drop', [ '$event' ])
  public onDrop(event: any): any {
    alert("hi");
  }
}
```

//app.component.css

```
.upload-drop-zone {
  min-height: 400px;
  min-width: 400px;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: dotted 1px #aaa;
}
```

Error is:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null
>       at FileUploadInputFor.push../node_modules/angular-material-fileupload/matFileUpload.esm.js.FileUploadInputFor.onDrop (matFileUpload.esm.js:7622)

File `matFileUpload.esm.js` belongs to the source code of `angular-material-fileupoad`

I am implementing this code using this link [code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-fileupload) on this link I am trying to implementing the second code of drag and drop file upload functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If the code you have posted above is the actual code, then from the reference link you have given [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-fileupload), it seems that you have not implemented the code properly.

Please look at the code [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-fileupload#drag-and-drop-example), you would see that with input, you will also need `<mat-file-upload-queue>...</mat-file-upload-queue>`, like below:

```html
<div [fileUploadInputFor]="fileUploadQueue" class="upload-drop-zone">
    Just drag and drop files here
</div>

<!-- You forgot below part --> 
<div style="width: 500px">
    <mat-file-upload-queue #fileUploadQueue
        [fileAlias]="'file'"
        [httpUrl]="'http://localhost:8180/jax-rs-jersey-application-sample'" multiple>

        <mat-file-upload [file]="file" [id]="i" *ngFor="let file of fileUploadQueue.files; let i = index"></mat-file-upload>
    </mat-file-upload-queue>
</div>
```

Comment: I need only one file should upload that is why I do not implement that code

Comment: I guess you need to understand the code more. Without `mat-file-upload-queue`, your code won't work. You are specifically giving reference to `mat-file-upload-queue`. Notice `[fileUploadInputFor]="fileUploadQueue"` in your first `div`, that means that you're giving reference to your `mat-file-upload-queue` with `#fileUploadQueue`.

Comment: I don't want to implement mat-file-upload-queue functionality that is why I do not implement this. if I want single file upload without mat-file-upload-queue what should I do?

Comment: The package which you are using angular-material-fileupload, itself required MatFileUploadModule. If you don't want to use MatFileUploadModule, please find out another package.

Comment: do we have the better implementation of MatFileUploadModule then please let me know,

Comment: Now you're changing your original question... :-)